# How to change jQuery css style to vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a code in jQuery and I need transform this to pure javascript code.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.baner').css({'transform':'translate3d(0px, '+(-($(this).scrollTop()/5))+"px"+', 0px'});
});
```

What i tried to do is:

```js
let win = document.querySelector(window);
let banner = document.getElementById('#baner');

win.addEventListener('scroll',function () {
        banner.css({'transform':'translate3d(0px, '+(-($(this).scrollTop()/5))+"px"+', 0px'});
    });
```

```html
<div class='#baner'>

</div>
```

How to change the jquery css code `.css({'transform':'translate3d(0px, '+(-($(this).scrollTop()/5))+"px"+', 0px'});` to JS?

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: `banner.style` gives you access to the `style` attribute of the banner element. As @Kalinauskas remarked, either use `getElementbyId('banner')` or `querySelector('#banner')` (probable typo in element id corrected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kalinauskas mentioned in his answer, you could use document.getElementById().

```
// () => {} is ES6 shorthand for a function (also called arrow function, read about it here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp
// Instead of the .css function for jQuery, you have .style.yourStyleAtributeHere
let banner = document.getElementById('baner');

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    banner.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, ' + (-(banner.scrollTop / 5))+"px"+', 0px'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let banner = document.getElementById('#baner');
```

Make sure this is correct:

```
let banner = document.getElementById('banner');
```

You don't use '#' since you already said it's an Id.

[document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: This is good, but it's not the only issue with the code in the question.